# Why video didn't display on my flutter application?

Tags: flutter, video, mp4, display, video-player

I'm using video_player to display video from assets folder but the video doesn't display.
this is my code :

```
  final controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/camion.mp4');
Positioned(
      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: VideoPlayer(controller),
      ),
    ),
```

And I'm sure that the video exists in assets folder

Comment: _"...But the video doesn't display"_ with no useful technical details included... **(1)** Is this Flutter app being tested on Android, iOS or the Web? **(2)** What is the video codec used inside the MP4? Is the codec supported by the testing system? Check your file with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline). It should be either H264 or H265. **(3)** Did you try to play a different file? [Download this one](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) and put into your Assets folder. **PS:** Has this package ever worked for any video file you've tested.

Comment: I'm testing on android . I created this video with canva I wnat juste to display it on the center if the screen. No this is the first time I try this package. the Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)

Comment: **(1)** OK. AVC1 is another name for H264 so video should work everywhere. I was worried the codec might be actually H265 which is not widely supported (but some phones still records as H265 video files in MP4). **(2)** As a starting point, does [this example code](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/play-video#complete-example) display an MP4  correctly? If yes, modify it to load from Assets folder, and if that works too then streamline it (reduce or remove the unnecessary parts) before using the smaller code in your own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the video_player dependency in the pubspec.yaml?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  video_player: ^2.2.18
```

If you have in your assets folder also a folder for videos, you need to index the folder on pubspec.yaml file like below:

```
assets:
 - assets/videos/
```

Import the package in your script:

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
```

Initialize your video player:

```
late VideoPlayerController controller;

controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/video.mp4');
controller.initialize().then((value){
  setState(() {});
});
```